# Should I resign the assembly with a new strong name key?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, strong-named-key

Should i be creating a new strong name key to resign a class assembly if i change the version information / number of the class assembly ?

For example : The class assembly version information is currently 1.0.0.0. 
              If I change the version no. to 1.1.0.0, should i create/resign the assembly? or does the strong name key use the new version information when the assembly is re-built?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely should not use a **new** strong name key; the strong name is **part** of the identity (the version is *another* part) - you should use the same strong name key that you used when you created the 1.0.0.0 dll.

Yes, you should create/resign - but with the same key.